Trying to use a for each loop to populate a dropdown list field using Google Script in a Google Form
I would like to use a Google Apps Script to build a form field drop down list referencing a range from a Google Sheet.
Before even trying to reference a range in a sheet, I built a simple array (colors) as a test.
I am trying to make a forEach loop populate the form field with the array. The forEach loop only displays the last element in the array to the field.
Note: I've commented out the code for adding field choices directly, which works.
Any direction would be most appreciated.
function testone(){

  const form = FormApp.create('Enter course and trainer(s)');
  const colorselect = form.addListItem();


/*
  colorselect.setChoices([
      colorselect.createChoice('red'), 
      colorselect.createChoice('blue'), 
      colorselect.createChoice("green"), 
      colorselect.createChoice("black"), 
      colorselect.createChoice("orange")
  ]);
*/


  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "black", "orange"];

  colors.forEach( (color) => { 
    colorselect.setChoices([
        colorselect.createChoice(color)
      ]);
  console.log(color);
  });


  // press Ctrl+Enter to see form urls
  Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
  Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());

}



In your forEach loop you are repeatedly defining the choices as only one value so at the end of the loop it will only be the last value.  Try this instead.  Build an array of choices
function testone(){

  let form = FormApp.create('Enter color');
  let colorselect = form.addListItem();

  let colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "black", "orange"];

  let choices = [];
  colors.forEach( c => {
      choices.push(colorselect.createChoice(c));
      console.log(c);
    }
  );
  colorselect.setChoices(choices);

  // press Ctrl+Enter to see form urls
  Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
  Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
}

Reference

Array.push()


Here is a shorter version instead of using forEach() you can use this method setChoiceValues().
function testone() {

  const form = FormApp.create('Enter color');
  const colorselect = form.addListItem();

  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "black", "orange"];
  colorselect.setChoiceValues(colors);

  // press Ctrl+Enter to see form urls
  Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
  Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());

}


Reference:
Class MultipleChoiceItem

Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you.
